# Existence of solution for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The Question:**

Consider the inhomogeneous ODE

$$y''(x)+y(x)=f(x) \; \; \; \; \; \; y(0)=0 \;,\;y(\pi)=1 \; \; \; \; \; \; 0<x<\pi$$

Give a condition on $f$ such that a solution exists

---

**My Thoughts:**

I get how if, for example, $f(x) = 0$ then the general solution is $y(x)=A\cos (x)+B\sin (x)$ so then *no* solutions exist.

By the Fredholm Alternative Theorem, the homogeneous adjoint problem

$$w''(x)+w(x)=0 \; \; \; \; \; \; w(0)=0 \;,\;w(\pi)=0 \; \; \; \; \; \; 0<x<\pi$$

has non-trivial solutions (namely $w(x)=C\sin (x)$), so that the original problem either has no solutions or non-unique solutions.

How should I proceed?

Comment: By $a$ do you mean $\pi$ ?

Comment: Yes, I have edited that

Comment: What is your $a$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\pi$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ z=y-\frac{1}{\pi}x $$
and then the equation becomes
$$ z''(x)+z(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi}x+f(x), \ z(0)=z(\pi)=0. $$
Note that the corresponding homogeneous equation
$$ z''(x)+z(x)=0, \ z(0)=z(\pi)=0 \tag{1} $$
has a solution $z=C\sin(x)$. Thus (1) has a solution iff
$$ \int_0^\pi\left[-\frac{1}{\pi}x+f(x)\right]\sin(x)dx=0$$
or
$$ \int_0^\pi f(x)\sin(x)dx=1. $$

Comment: I am maybe mistaken but $C \sin(nx)$ is a solution only for $n=1$, so the condition is the one you wrote but only for $n=1$.